# What should I store into db with oauth2 jwt authorization?

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, token, jwt

I want to use OAuth JWT token for authorization. By some reasons (osgi container) I can't use spring-oauth-security.

In the readme of spring-oauth-security I have found a quote:

The JSON Web Token (JWT) version of the store encodes all the data about the grant into the token itself (so no back end store at all which is a significant advantage).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/docs/oauth2.md

I am absolutely don't catch "no back end store at all". There are two cases in jwt:

- symmetric key or shared secret (HMAC);

Verifier key is a shared secret and is available by /token_key URL.
Question 1: I should store shared secret on server for each registered user. Why "no back end store at all"?

- asymmetric key (RS/ES);

/token_key returns public key (without principal).

Question 2: But why we use only one public key for all users? It is unable to generate more than one private key for the same public key in rsa, isn't it? Only one pair private key - public key is allowed in RSA.

I don't understand a flow and why "no back end store at all".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not use different keys per user but per Identity Provider.

Identity Provider signs a JWT with a key and you are able to validate it for each user without a backend lookup. For JWT validation you only need a key related to the Identity Provider - even if you store it on some DB, you could fetch it once and cache it. For assymetric keys, OIDC even defines a URL to fetch the public key(s) used for signature.

The key is used to trust the Identity Provider and thus implicitly the identities it provides.

This is quite good article on the topic:
https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Comment: Secret per Identity provider, you are right! Thanks, I get it now. Nice article, by the way, I like it.